# Implement a stack using a linked list

Tags: c, stack

I am to implement a stack in C using a linked list. My code is below. My design:

1. I use `stack_` prefix to each function, and each function has a `Stack* self` pointer. This is similar to object-oriented languages’ bundling of data and methods. I do not know how idiomatic this is in C.
2. Each function returns a `bool` indicating success or failure. A more detailed implementation would have error codes and messages. I do not know how idiomatic this is in C.
3. The `stack_init` function does not call `malloc`, so that one could define an instance of `Stack` locally, as in the test methods below.
4. I used `int` as the type of data, but this could be modified for other types. I did not use `void*` since `void*` would lose type safety.

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* root;
} Stack;

bool stack_init(Stack* self);
bool stack_delete(Stack* self);
bool stack_pop(Stack* self, int* data);
bool stack_push(Stack* self, int data);

#endif  // STACK_H_
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

bool stack_init(Stack* self) {
  if (self == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  self->root = NULL;
  return true;
}

bool stack_delete(Stack* self) {
  Node* next;
  while (self->root != NULL) {
    next = self->root->next;
    free(self->root);
    self->root = next;
  }

  return true;
}

bool stack_push(Stack* self, int data) {
  if (self == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (node == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  node->data = data;
  node->next = self->root;
  self->root = node;

  return true;
}

bool stack_pop(Stack* self, int* data){
  Node* root = self->root;
  if (root == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  *data = root->data;
  self->root = root->next;
  free(root);

  return true;
}
```

**stack_test.c**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "stack.h"

static void test_null_stack_should_fail_to_init() {
  // arrange
  Stack* stack = NULL;

  // act
  assert(!stack_init(stack));
}

static void test_empty_stack() {
  // arrange
  Stack stack;

  // act
  assert(stack_init(&stack));
  assert(stack_delete(&stack));
}

static void test_push_then_pop() {
  // arrange
  Stack stack;
  stack_init(&stack);
  stack_push(&stack, 1);
  stack_push(&stack, 2);
  stack_push(&stack, 3);
  int data;

  // act
  assert(stack_pop(&stack, &data));
  assert(data == 3);
  assert(stack_pop(&stack, &data));
  assert(data == 2);
  assert(stack_pop(&stack, &data));
  assert(data == 1);
  assert(!stack_pop(&stack, &data));
  assert(stack_delete(&stack));
}

static void test_push() {
  // arrange
  Stack stack;
  stack_init(&stack);
  stack_push(&stack, 1);
  stack_push(&stack, 2);
  stack_push(&stack, 3);

  // act
  assert(stack_delete(&stack));
}

int main() {
  test_null_stack_should_fail_to_init();
  test_empty_stack();
  test_push_then_pop();
  test_push();
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but you will probably want to add more methods and keep track of the stack size before it is fully usable. Take [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) from C++ as a reference interface.

Answer (score 5):

- `stack_delete` only returns `true`. If a return value from a function carries no information, better make it `void`.
- There is no consistency in testing parameters. Some functions test for `self` not being null, other directly proceed to calculating `self->root`.
- The `Stack` existence is only justifiable if it has more data members than just `root`. As @glampert mentioned in comments, tracking size is one of the candidates. On the other hand,  abandoning `Stack` for good, and letting client manage the root, as in

  ```
  Node * stack_push(Node * root, data);
  ....

  root = stack_push(root, data);
  ```

  is also a viable strategy.
- It would be nice to provide a non-destructive `top()` interface to access the root data. There is even a popular belief that a `pop`-like function should *only* pop an element from the top of stack (as opposed to pop element and return data); in this school of thought `top()` is a must.

Comment: Disagree with point 3; it abstracts implementation details from clients. Relatedly, it makes the client code easier to read.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. Abstracting implementation is a good strategy as long as it serves a purpose. Abstraction for the sake of abstraction is not.

Comment: Suppose you were to change it to `Node*`... and then in three months you want to add a size field?

Answer (score 3):

1. Unclear why `if (self == NULL)` in 2 of the 4 functions.  Suggest none or all 4.
2. A comment in `stack.h` concerning the meaning of the return value would be useful.  Assume user of `Stack` does not have access to `stack.c`.  Not clear is success happens with `true` or `false`.
3. Using `Node` and `node` is a bit too similar - differentiating only on 1 letter case.
4. Maybe want to add a `stack_empty()` query?
5. `typedef struct Node` is not needed in `stack.h`.  Suggest moving to `stack.c`
6. Maybe allow `stack_pop(Stack* self, int* data)` where `data` is `NULL` to pop without saving.